# What is the use of these Keycloak endpoints?

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services

What are the use of these keycloak endpoints?

```
issuer: "http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/dev",
authorization_endpoint: "http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/dev/protocol/openid-connect/auth",
token_endpoint: "http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/dev/protocol/openid-connect/token",
introspection_endpoint: "http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/dev/protocol/openid-connect/token/introspect",
userinfo_endpoint: "http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/dev/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo",
end_session_endpoint: "http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/dev/protocol/openid-connect/logout",
jwks_uri: "http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/dev/protocol/openid-connect/certs",
check_session_iframe: "http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/dev/protocol/openid-connect/login-status-iframe.html"
```

I know that on the `token_endpoint` I can get an access token, but I have no idea about the rest. I can see the data if I open the links but I have no idea when to use any of these in my java application.

Comment: Can you please tell me how did you get these list of endpoints? Got it http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/master/.well-known/openid-configuration.

Answer (score 4):

1. `issuer` - realm that issues an access_token
2. `introspection_endpoint` - checks validity of an access_token
3. `userinfo_endpoint` - accepts access_token & returns info about current logged user, that is clarified in MAPPER of client
4. `end_session_endpoint` - forces an access_token invalidation

More information about KeyCloak endpoints you can find [on baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/postman-keycloak-endpoints#keycloack-endpoints) (parts 5.1-5.5)

Answer (score 1):

Check OIDC discovery spec: https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-discovery-1_0.html#ProviderMetadata

```
    issuer
        REQUIRED. URL using the https scheme with no query or fragment component that the OP asserts as its Issuer Identifier. If Issuer discovery is supported (see Section 2), this value MUST be identical to the issuer value returned by WebFinger. This also MUST be identical to the iss Claim value in ID Tokens issued from this Issuer. 
    authorization_endpoint
        REQUIRED. URL of the OP's OAuth 2.0 Authorization Endpoint [OpenID.Core]. 
    token_endpoint
        URL of the OP's OAuth 2.0 Token Endpoint [OpenID.Core]. This is REQUIRED unless only the Implicit Flow is used. 
    userinfo_endpoint
        RECOMMENDED. URL of the OP's UserInfo Endpoint [OpenID.Core]. This URL MUST use the https scheme and MAY contain port, path, and query parameter components. 
    jwks_uri
        REQUIRED. URL of the OP's JSON Web Key Set [JWK] document. This contains the signing key(s) the RP uses to validate signatures from the OP. The JWK Set MAY also contain the Server's encryption key(s), which are used by RPs to encrypt requests to the Server. When both signing and encryption keys are made available, a use (Key Use) parameter value is REQUIRED for all keys in the referenced JWK Set to indicate each key's intended usage. Although some algorithms allow the same key to be used for both signatures and encryption, doing so is NOT RECOMMENDED, as it is less secure. The JWK x5c parameter MAY be used to provide X.509 representations of keys provided. When used, the bare key values MUST still be present and MUST match those in the certificate. 
    registration_endpoint
        RECOMMENDED. URL of the OP's Dynamic Client Registration Endpoint [OpenID.Registration]. 
    scopes_supported
        RECOMMENDED. JSON array containing a list of the OAuth 2.0 [RFC6749] scope values that this server supports. The server MUST support the openid scope value. Servers MAY choose not to advertise some supported scope values even when this parameter is used, although those defined in [OpenID.Core] SHOULD be listed, if supported. 
    response_types_supported
        REQUIRED. JSON array containing a list of the OAuth 2.0 response_type values that this OP supports. Dynamic OpenID Providers MUST support the code, id_token, and the token id_token Response Type values. 
    response_modes_supported
        OPTIONAL. JSON array containing a list of the OAuth 2.0 response_mode values that this OP supports, as specified in OAuth 2.0 Multiple Response Type Encoding Practices [OAuth.Responses]. If omitted, the default for Dynamic OpenID Providers is ["query", "fragment"]. 
    grant_types_supported
        OPTIONAL. JSON array containing a list of the OAuth 2.0 Grant Type values that this OP supports. Dynamic OpenID Providers MUST support the authorization_code and implicit Grant Type values and MAY support other Grant Types. If omitted, the default value is ["authorization_code", "implicit"]. 
    acr_values_supported
        OPTIONAL. JSON array containing a list of the Authentication Context Class References that this OP supports. 
    subject_types_supported
        REQUIRED. JSON array containing a list of the Subject Identifier types that this OP supports. Valid types include pairwise and public. 
    id_token_signing_alg_values_supported
        REQUIRED. JSON array containing a list of the JWS signing algorithms (alg values) supported by the OP for the ID Token to encode the Claims in a JWT [JWT]. The algorithm RS256 MUST be included. The value none MAY be supported, but MUST NOT be used unless the Response Type used returns no ID Token from the Authorization Endpoint (such as when using the Authorization Code Flow). 
    id_token_encryption_alg_values_supported
        OPTIONAL. JSON array containing a list of the JWE encryption algorithms (alg values) supported by the OP for the ID Token to encode the Claims in a JWT [JWT]. 
    id_token_encryption_enc_values_supported
        OPTIONAL. JSON array containing a list of the JWE encryption algorithms (enc values) supported by the OP for the ID Token to encode the Claims in a JWT [JWT]. 
    userinfo_signing_alg_values_supported
        OPTIONAL. JSON array containing a list of the JWS [JWS] signing algorithms (alg values) [JWA] supported by the UserInfo Endpoint to encode the Claims in a JWT [JWT]. The value none MAY be included. 
    userinfo_encryption_alg_values_supported
        OPTIONAL. JSON array containing a list of the JWE [JWE] encryption algorithms (alg values) [JWA] supported by the UserInfo Endpoint to encode the Claims in a JWT [JWT]. 
    userinfo_encryption_enc_values_supported
        OPTIONAL. JSON array containing a list of the JWE encryption algorithms (enc values) [JWA] supported by the UserInfo Endpoint to encode the Claims in a JWT [JWT]. 
    request_object_signing_alg_values_supported
        OPTIONAL. JSON array containing a list of the JWS signing algorithms (alg values) supported by the OP for Request Objects, which are described in Section 6.1 of OpenID Connect Core 1.0 [OpenID.Core]. These algorithms are used both when the Request Object is passed by value (using the request parameter) and when it is passed by reference (using the request_uri parameter). Servers SHOULD support none and RS256. 
    request_object_encryption_alg_values_supported
        OPTIONAL. JSON array containing a list of the JWE encryption algorithms (alg values) supported by the OP for Request Objects. These algorithms are used both when the Request Object is passed by value and when it is passed by reference. 
    request_object_encryption_enc_values_supported
        OPTIONAL. JSON array containing a list of the JWE encryption algorithms (enc values) supported by the OP for Request Objects. These algorithms are used both when the Request Object is passed by value and when it is passed by reference. 
    token_endpoint_auth_methods_supported
        OPTIONAL. JSON array containing a list of Client Authentication methods supported by this Token Endpoint. The options are client_secret_post, client_secret_basic, client_secret_jwt, and private_key_jwt, as described in Section 9 of OpenID Connect Core 1.0 [OpenID.Core]. Other authentication methods MAY be defined by extensions. If omitted, the default is client_secret_basic -- the HTTP Basic Authentication Scheme specified in Section 2.3.1 of OAuth 2.0 [RFC6749]. 
    token_endpoint_auth_signing_alg_values_supported
        OPTIONAL. JSON array containing a list of the JWS signing algorithms (alg values) supported by the Token Endpoint for the signature on the JWT [JWT] used to authenticate the Client at the Token Endpoint for the private_key_jwt and client_secret_jwt authentication methods. Servers SHOULD support RS256. The value none MUST NOT be used. 
    display_values_supported
        OPTIONAL. JSON array containing a list of the display parameter values that the OpenID Provider supports. These values are described in Section 3.1.2.1 of OpenID Connect Core 1.0 [OpenID.Core]. 
    claim_types_supported
        OPTIONAL. JSON array containing a list of the Claim Types that the OpenID Provider supports. These Claim Types are described in Section 5.6 of OpenID Connect Core 1.0 [OpenID.Core]. Values defined by this specification are normal, aggregated, and distributed. If omitted, the implementation supports only normal Claims. 
    claims_supported
        RECOMMENDED. JSON array containing a list of the Claim Names of the Claims that the OpenID Provider MAY be able to supply values for. Note that for privacy or other reasons, this might not be an exhaustive list. 
    service_documentation
        OPTIONAL. URL of a page containing human-readable information that developers might want or need to know when using the OpenID Provider. In particular, if the OpenID Provider does not support Dynamic Client Registration, then information on how to register Clients needs to be provided in this documentation. 
    claims_locales_supported
        OPTIONAL. Languages and scripts supported for values in Claims being returned, represented as a JSON array of BCP47 [RFC5646] language tag values. Not all languages and scripts are necessarily supported for all Claim values. 
    ui_locales_supported
        OPTIONAL. Languages and scripts supported for the user interface, represented as a JSON array of BCP47 [RFC5646] language tag values. 
    claims_parameter_supported
        OPTIONAL. Boolean value specifying whether the OP supports use of the claims parameter, with true indicating support. If omitted, the default value is false. 
    request_parameter_supported
        OPTIONAL. Boolean value specifying whether the OP supports use of the request parameter, with true indicating support. If omitted, the default value is false. 
    request_uri_parameter_supported
        OPTIONAL. Boolean value specifying whether the OP supports use of the request_uri parameter, with true indicating support. If omitted, the default value is true. 
    require_request_uri_registration
        OPTIONAL. Boolean value specifying whether the OP requires any request_uri values used to be pre-registered using the request_uris registration parameter. Pre-registration is REQUIRED when the value is true. If omitted, the default value is false. 
    op_policy_uri
        OPTIONAL. URL that the OpenID Provider provides to the person registering the Client to read about the OP's requirements on how the Relying Party can use the data provided by the OP. The registration process SHOULD display this URL to the person registering the Client if it is given. 
    op_tos_uri
        OPTIONAL. URL that the OpenID Provider provides to the person registering the Client to read about OpenID Provider's terms of service. The registration process SHOULD display this URL to the person registering the Client if it is given.

Additional OpenID Provider Metadata parameters MAY also be used. Some are defined by other specifications, such as OpenID Connect Session Management 1.0 [OpenID.Session].
```

Some data are optional/recommended only, so Keycloak doesn't provide all of them.